# installing postgresql and pgadmin4

Tags: postgresql, macos, installation, pgadmin-4

I've been having problems installing postgresql and pgadmin 4 on Mac m2. when I try opening pg admin 4 it closes unexpectedly with the error pgadmin quit unexpectedly. Would appreciate any help as I need to do  a task and submit tomorrow. Thanks in advance x

Comment: For PostgreSQL: https://postgresapp.com Don't know about pgAdmin, I always try to stay away from it, as far as possible. I prefer other SQL clients, and psql is always your best friend on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Frank, if you can try using the cli.
However, running it as a docker container works on my M1 macbook.

https://hub.docker.com/r/dpage/pgadmin4/